# How to stop smalling page when small windows?

Tags: html, css

When I open "inspect element" in right side of page it begins to small down, and whole style is out...
How can I stop it? Make it to become scrollable?
I tried adding to css:

```
html{
     overflow: scroll;
}
```

But it didn't work...
You got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll typically get a scroll bar when elements are fixed in size. Meaning they have a fixed width. Set your elements to a pixel value instead of percentages. Stackoverflow for example stays in place when i open the chrome inspector.

Note that this is very counter intuitive to that of responsive design. Your site should change size, and adapt to that of the screen.

Comment: I know what you mean, but something is not right about this... When I set pixel value, how do I set it to change every time the size of window does? I could add there something like "counter(value-10px)" but how do I get the "value" to css?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean then. As your comment seems contradictory to your question. Do you want the window to maintain width but scroll vertically? I think you should post example code or a js fiddle showing your problem.

Comment: There is not a problem that I could show you in js fiddle, and no, I want it to scroll horizontally, you know... When I have the element inspector I have it on left side of the window and the page totally redesigns... like inputs go one under one and icons go under other element etc... And I want it to be scrollable but not hidden (to not change anything just add one scrollbar on the bottom of window)...